# SQL like: How to calculate intersection and union of <item,user> data

Tags: sql, join, count, union, intersection

Need help in SQL:

I have a data with the following columns:

- ItemId
- UserId

Each row indicates that some item was bought by some user.
Example:

```
ItemId UserId

   200    user1

   200    user3

   200    user4

   300    user5

   300    user3
```

for each  I would like to calculate the following output table:

- users(i) : number of users bought i
- users(j) : number of users bought j
- users(i, j) : number of users bought both i and j
- users(i, ~j) : number of users bought i but not j
- users(~i, j) : number of users bought j but not i

Example of output (from the example above):

```
i_itemId  j_itemId  users(i)  users(j)  users(i,j)  users(i,~j)  users(~i, j)

200  200  3  3  3  0  0

200  300  3  2  1  2  1

300  300  2  2  2  0  0

300  200  3  2  1  1  2
```

**Note**:

1. The data table is huge (11 GB) located on the cloud. I have a framework of SQL to work with. So I cannot download the file and run python (for example)
   So the solution has to be written in SQL in efficient way
2. The solution does not have to be one single SQL statement.
3. I am looking for an efficient solution
4. We can assume that  is a key
5. If someone have a better alternative for the Question header here i will be glad to update it :)

Comment: Could you please sample data of i & J as well for quick review.

Comment: State, and use the tag, of the SQL language/environment you're using

Comment: i gave a small example @RajatJaiswal

Comment: What if a user bought an item more than once? Does this count as one or the number of actual purchases?

Comment: @stickybit, let's assume that <itemId,userId> is a key in the table

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using MS SCOPE language (an SQL like for big data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an "easy" way to accomplish this.  One method is rather brute force:  use a `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then use subqueries for each of the individual counts:

```
select i1.itemid, i2.itemid, i1.num as cnt1, i2.num as cnt2,
       (select count(*)
        from t u1 join
             t u2
             on u1.userid = u2.userid
        where u1.itemid = i1.itemid and u2.itemid = i2.itemid
       ) as cnt_1_2,
       (select count(*)
        from t u1 left join
             t u2
             on u1.userid = u2.userid and u2.itemid = i2.itemid
        where u1.itemid = i1.itemid and u2.itemid is null
       ) as cnt_1_not2,
       (select count(*)
        from t u1 left join
             t u2
             on u1.userid = u2.userid and u1.itemid = i1.itemid
        where u2.itemid = i2.itemid and u1.itemid is null
       ) as cnt_not1_2
from (select itemid, count(*) as num from t group by itemid) i1 cross join
     (select itemid, count(*) as num from t group by itemid) i2;
```

Comment: thanks
in all your join statements you force that itemId == itemId.
But i need cross join to get calculations for each item pairs

Also, it doesn't have to be one SQL statement. That won't be efficient

Comment: @SamerAamar . . . The `from` clause does a `cross join`, so I don't understand that part of your comment.  The single query should be reasonably efficient with the right indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe

1) Create a temporary table to gather the I and J totals.

> Disclaimer :
>   This example uses a MS SQL server datatype: INT.
>   So change it to the numeric type that your RDBMS supports.
>   Btw, in MS SQL Server, temporary tables start with #

```
create table TempTotals (iItemId int, jItemId int, TotalUsers int);
```

2) Fill it up with totals

```
delete from TempTotals;
insert into TempTotals (iItemId, jItemId, TotalUsers)
select 
    t1.ItemId as iItemId, 
    t2.ItemId as jItemId, 
    count(distinct t1.UserId) as TotalUsers
from YourTable t1
full join YourTable t2 on (t1.UserId = t2.UserId)
group by t1.ItemId, t2.ItemId;
```

3) Self-join the temporary table to get all the totals

```
select 
 ij.iItemId, 
 ij.jItemId,
 i.TotalUsers as Users_I,
 j.TotalUsers as Users_J,
 ij.TotalUsers as Users_I_and_J, 
 (i.TotalUsers - ij.TotalUsers) as Users_I_no_J,
 (j.TotalUsers - ij.TotalUsers) as Users_J_no_I
from TempTotals ij
left join TempTotals i on (i.iItemId = ij.iItemId and i.iItemId = i.jItemId)
left join TempTotals j on (j.jItemId = ij.jItemId and j.iItemId = j.jItemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle Database, you can compare nested tables (collections) with the multiset operators. And get the number of elements in a collection with cardinality.

So what you can do is:

- Group by itemid, collecting all the users into a nested table
- Cross join the output of this with itself
- Use the multiset intersect/except operators to get number of elements in the sets as needed

Which looks a little like:

```
create table t (
  ItemId int, UserId varchar2(10)
);
insert into t values (   200  ,  'user1');
insert into t values (   200  ,  'user3');
insert into t values (   200  ,  'user4');
insert into t values (   300  ,  'user5');
insert into t values (   300  ,  'user3');

commit;

create or replace type users_t as table of varchar2(10);
/

with grps as (
  select itemid, cast ( collect ( userid ) as users_t ) users
  from   t
  group  by itemid
)
  select g1.itemid i, g2.itemid j,
         cardinality ( g1.users ) num_i,
         cardinality ( g2.users ) num_j,
         cardinality ( g1.users multiset intersect g2.users ) i_and_j,
         cardinality ( g1.users multiset except g2.users ) i_not_j,
         cardinality ( g2.users multiset except g1.users ) j_not_i
  from   grps g1
  cross  join grps g2;

I     J     NUM_I   NUM_J   I_AND_J   I_NOT_J   J_NOT_I   
  200   200       3       3         3         0         0 
  200   300       3       2         1         2         1 
  300   200       2       3         1         1         2 
  300   300       2       2         2         0         0
```

If necessary, you may be able to get more performance by skipping the except operators when i = j, e.g.:

```
case 
  when g1.itemid = g2.itemid then 0 
  else cardinality ( g1.users multiset intersect g2.users )
end
```